# How is this site using a hi-res video as a background?

Tags: css, video

http://freelance.tv/

Seems like this video is too high-resolution to be downloaded that quickly — what is the trick being used here?

Comment: To me it looks like they just have a 720p(not the best but good)HD video that's only 19 seconds long at 8.9mb.    Most browsers with a high speed connection would be able to render it fairly quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The video does not seem to be higher than 720p, once I opened the page the video stopped a few times to buffer but with high-speed internet, it will load fairly quickly.